# Can a Large creature enter Leomund's Tiny Hut from below?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, creature-size

The other day one of my spellcasters conjured [*Leomund's tiny hut*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-hut) so his team could sleep in peace:

> A 10-foot-radius immobile dome of force springs into existence around and above you and remains stationary for the duration. The spell ends if you leave its area.
>
> Nine creatures of Medium size or smaller can fit inside the dome with you. The spell fails if its area includes a larger creature or more than nine creatures. Creatures and objects within the dome when you cast this spell can move through it freely. All other creatures and objects are barred from passing through it. Spells and other magical effects can't extend through the dome or be cast through it. The atmosphere inside the space is comfortable and dry, regardless of the weather outside.
>
> Until the spell ends, you can command the interior to become dimly lit or dark. The dome is opaque from the outside, of any color you choose, but it is transparent from the inside.

I had assassins waiting for them for an ambush. One of my assassins was a Druid who transformed into a Earth Elemental and earth glided underneath the *tiny hut* to get inside. My thought was that if the earth elemental burrowed underneath and reappeared inside the *tiny hut* it would break the hut because it's a Large elemental. Will this happen, or does it not count because it wasn't included during the casting time?

Answer (score 23):

RAW is unclear, and the [tweets from Mr. Crawford are contradicting each other](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/823774362293542912) (and are unofficial now).

But logic, game history, balance and plain common sense dictates that [Leomund's Tiny Hut is not accessible from below](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/73909/9552).

Comment: His comment "it is a hemisphere" is what closes out [that previous question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73879/22566) on this spell?  Right?

Comment: So what other ways can you get around it? I know dispel magic or counter spell and Breath Weapon can also be used to hit creature inside of it. But what else?

Comment: Maybe disintegrate?  Not raw, but it is a stowe of force abs wall of force is breakable by disintegrate.

Comment: Since [Crawford's tweets are no longer official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/with-the-2019-sage-advice-compendium-release-are-jeremy-crawfords-tweets-consi/140222#140222), this answer would be improved by citing the relevant rule and/or aspect of the spell description (as referenced in the tweet itself).

Answer (score 8):

In [previous editions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/tinyHut.htm), the hemispherical interior was completely protected by a spherical shell: "*Half the sphere projects above the ground, and the lower hemisphere passes through the ground*"... "*The interior of the hut is a hemisphere*". 5e [reworded](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/spells/tinyHut.htm) the spell, but I see no indication that the writers now intended it to be vulnerable to burrowing, shoveling or flooding. Leomund was no fool of a wizard.