# Is it possible for Leomund's Tiny Hut to be lifted?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I've been trying to come up with creative ways to get around Leomund's Tiny Hut and another idea recently came to me.  When I first started, I had looked into burrowing creatures that would penetrate the hut from beneath.  There is however this [topic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73879/can-one-enter-leomunds-tiny-hut-from-below) that really makes sense with the Hut having a floor they cannot enter.  Then I had another idea:

Could burrowing creatures lift the hut while burrowing in an attempt to cause a Dexterity saving throw to stay inside the Hut or be thrown out?  Same would apply to an ability such as Wall of Stone/Force causing the Hut to lift and tilt.  So how well anchored is the hut and can that anchor be affected?

Comment: Hi, I reworded your title into more of a question. Feel free to change it back/to something else if you don't like my change. You really badly want to get through your players' tiny hut, don't you?

Comment: I hate the Tiny Hut, but I also want to do creative things that doesn't take away from the player taking it as a learned spell.  Occasionally there will be creatures with Dispel Magic, but I feel like that's a cop out and really poor storytelling.  I had a Ogre come and literally use the hut as a back scratcher for 1d4 hours (rolled a 3) and that prevented anyone from sleeping well so took longer to get a full rest.

I really enjoy using their strengths or best strategies and nullifying them after they've used them a few times.  Give them the 'oh no my go to didn't work, what next' scenario.

Comment: Reposting [this question about circumventing Tiny Hut](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137458/realistically-does-leomund-s-tiny-hut-allow-for-indefinite-long-rests-in-a-dung). You may also want to hop into [chat] for a place to talk about your concern in a non-Q&A format.

Comment: By the time you get around the hut they will be safely camped in a magnificent mansion 

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## RAW: You can't lift the Tiny Hut

The description of [Tiny hut](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-hut) says :

> A 10-foot-radius **immobile** dome of force springs into existence around and above you and **remains stationary** for the duration.

(emphasis mine)

It seems like the Hut really can't move.

Comment: I guess the deeper question becomes, what the immobility constitutes.  If the ground its on is moved, how does that affect the hut.

Best parallel I can make is that Mjolnir (Thor's Hammer) in the Marvel Universe cannot be lifted by anyone unworthy.  Well, once Hulk literally lifted a chunk of the earth that the hammer was sitting on with the hammer still upon that chunk.

Comment: @ConfusedDM In that case check this question out : https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134302/does-a-persistent-spell-effect-cast-on-a-moving-platform-move-with-the-platform?rq=1